# Is there a way to make an exception for the beforeunload method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, https, e-commerce

I would like to make an exception for the beforeunload event in javascript. I mean exception as in that I would like to exclude a url or form button from this not in the sense of an error handling exception. I will post my relavant javascript code right now.

```
if(loggedin == 1){
    $(window).bind('click', function(event) {
        if(event.target.href) $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
    });
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event) {
        $('div.offerWindow').css("visibility", "visible");
        return 'Press "Stay on Page" and get a special offer!';
    });

    function Close(){
        $('div.offerWindow').css("visibility", "hidden");
    };
}
```

The site is at http://www.redlakewalleye.com when in the shopping cart where this javascript is. The site then redirects to https://redlakefisheries.worldsecuresystems.com/OrderRetrievev2.aspx... when the checkout button is clicked. I need to make an exception for this url, I am not sure if it would be a paremeter or what. Any help or alternate solutions would be awesome.

Comment: onbeforeunload is the worst event (except onunload!) to deal with. That said, i don't really understand what you are tring to do. What is "checkout button"? Is the code you posted inside "checkout" click handler? You should really think about improving your question

Comment: actually there are very legit scenarios when your only chance is to use these events...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, then: in that button's `onclick` simply unbind the `onbeforeunload` event for the window.

Edit:
In your code above you "bind" (or set) the `beforeunload` event handler:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event) {
    $('div.offerWindow').css("visibility", "visible");
    return 'Press "Stay on Page" and get a special offer!';
});
```

So, in the `onclick` event handler for the button in question (you have that code somewhere) you "unbind" the above:

```
$(window).unbind('beforeunload');
```

I think that's all.

Comment: could you give me an example of it? I don't understand the bind and unbind events very well. Thanks.